# Difference between getKey and getRow in Astyanax

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

What is the difference in calling getKey and getRow?

From javadoc,

getKey: Query a single key

getRow: Query a single row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently nothing.  getRow() just calls getKey()

From ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java

```
@Override
public RowQuery<K, C> getRow(K rowKey) {
    return getKey(rowKey);
}
```